# RE - regex - как изменить порядок поиска

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

```
import re

stroka="start_dfd8357dfd_stop_dlfjdsf_start_kljf8998_stop_sfsdjflkjf_start_fjslkdjfdls_stop"

t=re.findall(r'start(.*)stop', stroka)
print (t)
```

В строке `stroka` есть три набора `start` - `stop`. Я хочу вытащить три последовательности между ними: между первыми старт-стоп, между вторыми старт-стоп, и между третьими старт-стоп.

Но `re` имеет немного другую логику. Он находит `start` с начала, а потом с конца начинает искать `stop`, находит последний!

Есть ли какой-то параметр, который скажет `re`, что после start нужно искать ближайший следующий `stop`, а не искать с конца.

**Сейчас я получаю результат:**

```
['_dfd8357dfd_stop_dlfjdsf_start_kljf8998_stop_sfsdjflkjf_start_fjslkdjfdls_']
```

**А хочу получать:**

```
['_dfd8357dfd_', '_kljf8998_', '_fjslkdjfdls_']
```

Comment: Тысячи их... Читайте про нежадную квантификацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы найти все вхождения, а не только самое длинное, нужно ограничить жадность квантификатора, добавив после него вопросительный знак:

```
t=re.findall(r'start(.*?)stop', stroka)
```

http://www.ilnurgi1.ru/docs/python/modules/re.html

Comment: Да, это оно. Спасибо большое!